# background subtractor for opencv=3.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1, background-subtraction

```
//cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg = cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
cv::Ptr< BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 >createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
bg.set("history", 1000);
bg.set("nmixtures", 3);
bg.set("backgroundRatio", 0.7);
bg.set("detectShadows", false);

//background subtractor for the filterTotalBackground results
//cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg2 = cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
Ptr< BackgroundSubtractorMOG2  >createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 ();
bg2.set("history", 1000);
bg2.set("nmixtures", 3);
bg2.set("backgroundRatio", 0.7);
bg2.set("detectShadows", false);
```

need to use this in a single code but I'm in confusion to where to declare bg and bg2 in the above shown code.the earlier commented lines are giving me errors.so if anyone could suggest a feasible solution, then it would be a great help

> bg->operator()(total, fore);            //error is here

```
//Computes a background image.
//C++: void BackgroundSubtractor::getBackgroundImage(OutputArray backgroundImage) const¶
bg->getBackgroundImage(back);


//find the moving objects in the frame and cv::erode the image
bg2->operator()(frame, fore2);    //error is here
bg2->getBackgroundImage(back2);
cv::erode(fore2, fore2, cv::Mat());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `->` operator to get the `cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` object.

```
cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> bg = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
bg->setHistory(1000);
bg->setNMixtures(3);
bg->setBackgroundRatio(0.7);
bg->setDetectShadows(false);
```

Another error:

You must change:

```
bg->operator()(frame, fore);
```

to

```
bg->apply(frame, fore);
```

I see that you are using an old tutorial, you could use this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html)

Comment: thanks it worked. but can u help me out with the error which is caused due to the changes u said . the error is like

Comment: /humans/package_bgs/MovingDetection.cpp:610:22: error: 'struct cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2>' has no member named 'operator()'
         bg2.operator()(frame, fore2);

Comment: should i comment my error lines and then add your edited snippet? if i do so then the whole snippet gives an error. and if i dont comment them then it  gives  no member named opertor

Comment: THANKYOU FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP. IT WORKED...:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got it working changing, in **ofxCvMOG2.cpp**,

```
mog2 = new cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

by:

```
mog2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500,16,true);
```

That means, setting history, threshold and detect shadows at the beginning, and commenting:

```
mog2->set("nmixtures", nMixtures);
mog2->set("detectShadows",1);
```

Comment: Please don't add follow up questions in answers. Feel free to post a new question, and link to this one if it's relevant.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I posted it in the wrong post! Thanks for saying it

Comment: No worries. Also, I just edited out the follow up part of the answer, on the assumption that the rest of it does answer the OP's question. If it doesn't (i.e. the entire answer was meant to be a separate question), you can go ahead and delete this answer.